# Is there a way to get the size of a pane in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I've just resized a pane using by holding leader (C-b) and using up/down arrow keys. I know I could just use percentages, but it would be handy if tmux told me the sizing of current layout.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In *tmux* 1.7 and later you can extract the pane dimensions like this:

```
tmux display -p -t s:0.1 '#{pane_width}x#{pane_height}'
```

Check out the man page for all the variations that “*target-pane*” supports (`s:0.1` above means pane 1 of window 0 of the session named “s”) and the list of all the other “format” variables (the `#{…}` bits).

Comment: FYI: If you leave off the '-t xxx' argument, you get values for the currently focused pane.